# how to strip a set of characters from a string in a program in python

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
string = input("Enter a string:")
print(string)

characters = input("Enter the characters you would like to make disappear:")
print(characters)

print(string.replace("characters"," "))
```

I need to display variable string without the entered characters in variable characters

Comment: i think you'll need to loop through each letter you want to disappear and replace it

Comment: Make characters a list, then iterate over that list and call `string.replace(listitem, "")` on each one. Heck, you don't even need to make it a list first, just iterate over `characters` char by char.

Comment: Don't use `string` as name, it's module from standard library

Comment: @buran As long as they are not using the string module, i think its fine to use `string` as a variable name.

Comment: @Billy, it's fine until it's not and bites them. Better learn not to commit such errors. SO is full of questions about errors due to name collisions with built-in modules.

Comment: @MattDMo, I just looped through each letter and replaced it, but now what the program does is replace them individually line after line and I want it to replace all the letters in a single line.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the code you're currently using, as well as the input, the output you're getting, and the output you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the characters, and replace each one by one

### Example

```py
for ch in "characters":
    string.replace(ch, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using `re` to remove all vowels in your string:

```py
>>> import re
>>> characters_to_remove = "aeiouy"
>>> my_string = "my string"
>>> re.sub(f"[{characters_to_remove}]", "", my_string)
'm strng'
```